# css positioning dropdown submenu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, submenu

In my website there are css sub menus. Problem is last two sub menus gets out from the screen.

[image]

How can I maintain position of this sub menus?

There are some minor css tweak & code is so lengthy so I am not posting entire code here. Here is the link of live site which has the problem [www.brandstik.in](http://brandstik.in/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target your last 2 or 3 menu-links to manage their sub-menu positions as:

**CSS**:

```
.main-category-nav > li:nth-last-child(1) ul.super-child, 
.main-category-nav > li:nth-last-child(2) ul.super-child, 
.main-category-nav > li:nth-last-child(3) ul.super-child {
    right: 0;
}
```

This will change sub-menu positions of your last 3 children links.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ul.super-child:last-child, ul.super-child:nth-last-child(2) {
   right: 0px;
}
```

The 2 container will fit into the view now.

Comment: But Now it creates same problem in Left side